# Can't move components at the begining

Tags: java, layout, gridbaglayout

I did a JPane p, put it on "EAST" side. Then I set GridBagLayout() as my pane layout. 
And when i add buttons, they are on the center, but I want to see them in left top corner .

This is how i add buttoms.

```
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
this.b1 = new JButton("Button 1");
gbc.gridx = 0;
gbc.gridy = 0;
p1.add(b1, gbc);
```

[image]

Comment: You probably need to set the `weighty` to something which is not 0. Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Be sure to copy-paste your code to a *new project* and make sure it compiles and runs before posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

Try to youse a `GridBagConstraints` for example :

```
pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

button = new JButton("Button 1");

if (shouldWeightX) {
    c.weightx = 0.5;
}

c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
c.gridx = 0;
c.gridy = 0;
pane.add(button, c);
```